# Doesn't kill the process

Tags: 12.04, process, kill

I have to kill mysqld process but after I had killed the same process started in a different way as a new pid number. For example:

```
ak@ak-EasyNote-TM98:~$ ps -aux|grep mysql 
mysqld start mysql     6894  7.0  1.4 484304 42940 ?        Ssl  21:13 
...
```

And than I get this:

```
ak@ak-EasyNote-TM98:~$ ps -aux|grep mysqld 
mysqld start mysql     6894  7.0  1.4 484304 42940 ?        Ssl  21:13
...
```

How can I find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

That's because mysqld_safe. mysql's watchdog, notices it and respawns it. You should stop mysql using the provided init script: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

Comment: That is correct, and another reason should be noted: MySQL needs to safely close certain files with writebacks, especially in reference to MyISAM and InnoDB table data. Failure to shutdown correctly may cause a repair next MySQL startup, or even ***severe database corruption***.